# How do I cluster documents using topic models?

Tags: clustering, k-means, topic-models

Let us say I have a topic probability per document, for example:

```
Doc1: Science:0.6, History:0.2, Politics:0.1, Sports:0.1
Doc2: Science:0.3, History:0.5, Politics:0.1, Sports:0.1
Doc3: Science:0.8, History:0.1, Politics:0.05, Sports:0.05
Doc4: Science:0.2, History:0.2, Politics:0.4, Sports:0.2
```

It is fairly clear that Doc1 is similar to Doc3. If I use topic modeling as a dimensionality reduction tool, can I use clustering methods to cluster documents on topic space? What would be the appropriate clustering technique and distance function? Will K-means with Euclidean distance suffice? (It seems weird to calculate eucledian distance between two probability distribution)

Also, topics might be correlated, what would be a way to handle that?

Comment: Yes, Euclidian distances have been used, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16010600/1036500) for an example and further reference.

Comment: For measuring the distance between 2 distributions, you could try Jensen-Shannon distance (which is the square root of Jensen-Shannon divergence).